# Customize "export users" result

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay

In Liferay there is a "Export Users" button that exports a CSV file of all users. Is there a way that you can extend the fields that are fetched from multiple database tables? Default values are only full name and email.

Answer (score 2):

Yes sure there is in your `portal-ext.properties` check for `users.export.csv.fields=fullName,emailAddress`. You can add columns from User_ table here.